# Complete list of theme elements to colorize?

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

Is there a list of all the customizable theme color elements for a visual studio theme ?

For example, I don't know how to customize the file browser color, such as the equivalent to hover one, or the scroll bar.

In textmate themes, I can't find such elements.
Or maybe you can point me to 'high-contrast' theme source, as it gots all these elements customized.

For example, how to you change color of the scroll bar ?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a full list, but here is the high contrast theme: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/hc_black.json, also take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/theme-kimbie-dark/package.json. You could try to set uiTheme to vs-dark or vs-light. This might change the explorer color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code's background, text, and language syntax colorization can be defined through a theme but also through user settings.
Since 1.12 you can also theme any other view in VSCode. Check out https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes for details and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference for a list of all colors.

Comment: Ok i see. It is too bad that non editor code cannot be customized.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a list, but I found this information that can be useful.
Yo can inspect the code and find the scope name t customize it

[Scope inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector)